# JQuery Check for Class in ID ..if exists change img src content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code:

```
<img id="myid" class="myclass" src="image1.png" />
```

What I need to do is:

if myid contains a class="myclass" then change `src="image1.png" to src="image2.png"`

How can I do that with JQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($('#myid').hasClass('myclass')){
    $('#myid').attr('src','image2.png');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var e = $("#myid");
var ans = e.hasClass("myclass");
if(ans){
  e.attr("src","image2.png");
}
$("#debug").text(ans+", src"+ e.attr("src"));
```

working example http://jsbin.com/evipuz/edit#javascript,html,live